# Creating a Loop in Python (Pandas) that iterates through row names and creates a grouped multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, loops, finance, multi-index

I'm working on a data set that consists of S&P 500 stock data. I've created a dataframe for the companies that I want to look at, and the data looks like this: 
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GimEa.png)

[image: DataFrame]

Since there are multiple entries for each company (the name column refers to their stock ticker name, BAC being Bank of America, etc), I want to be able to create a multi-index that allows me to index by the ticker name as well as the date, so that all stocks for a certain company are first grouped by their ticker name, and then there's another level of index for each entry, which would be the date. I would want it to look something like this: 
[Finished DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FuKO.png)
[image]

Any help would be appreciated since I'm a complete beginner, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is a bit unclear to me, here's my two cents

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

BANKS = ['BAC', 'C']
COLS = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [BANKS, COLS],
        names=['Bank', 'Stock Info']
        )
dates = pd.date_range(date(2018, 1, 1), date(2018, 1, 5))
data = np.random.randint(
        low=0, high=2, size=(len(BANKS)*len(COLS), len(dates))
        )
s = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=indices, columns=dates)
```

The `MultiIndex.from_product` multiplies the `BANKS` and `COLS`, creating multi-level indices.

Comment: You need to provide us an example, so that we could understand your situation, such as providing a small set of data.